# Trim the String

Tags: swift

Example:

> abcdefgh\nbbbbbbbbb

Whenever i encounter "\n", i want to trim the string so that i can get the new string which is before "\n". The result should be abcdefgh.

How can i do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import Foundation
var str = "abcdefgh\nbbbbbbbbb"
var splitStr =  str.components(separatedBy: .newlines) 
print(splitStr[0])
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58cf668ccb8af8164e56df4e)**</kbd>

If you want only first item

Try like this

```
let splitStr =  str.components(separatedBy: .newlines).first
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58cf6756cb8af8164e56df4f)**</kbd>

Comment: `let firstLine =  str.components(separatedBy: .newlines).first`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The Swift and javascript way is to use the global split function.

```
var text_string = "abcdefgh\nbbbbbbbbb"

var arr = text_string.characters.split{$0 == "\n"}.map(String.init)
var need: String = arr[0]

var drop: String? = arr.count > 1 ? arr[1] : nil

print(need)
```